# Cloudera Manager CDH cluster installation failed

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I am newbie in CDH4 and trying to install CDH4 on the local machine where the cloudera manager is running. After the login, display page(localhost:7180/cmf/express-wizard/hosts) showing me

```
cdh4-1.vm
cdh4-2.vm
cdh4-3.vm
```

and I getting the below error

```
ExpandedQuery Hostname(FQDN) IP Address     Currently Managed   Result
cdh4-1.vm     cdh4-1.vm      92.242.132.27  No                  Could not connect to host.
cdh4-2.vm     cdh4-2.vm      92.242.132.27  No                  Could not connect to host.
cdh4-3.vm     cdh4-3.vm      92.242.132.27  No                  Could not connect to host.
```

Comment: i follow this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-d40H96QAIs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its my mistake,my hostname configuration was wrong.